# transformation of data for the multi step sequence for lstm timeseries

Tags: python, time-series, pandas-groupby, lstm, data-science

i have a dataframe like below and i want to create a multisequence data at customer level.please help me on this.

Kindly note a customer can have 10 rows and other customer can have 14 rows.

Dataframe(input) :

```
Date    Customer    Price
1/6/2019    A   855    
1/7/2019    A   989    
1/8/2019    A   454    
1/9/2019    A   574    
1/10/2019   A   395    
1/1/2019    A   162
1/2/2019    A   123
1/3/2019    A   342
1/4/2019    A   232
1/5/2019    A   657
1/6/2019    B   875    
1/7/2019    B   999    
1/8/2019    B   434    
1/9/2019    B   564    
1/10/2019   B   345    
1/10/2019   B   798
1/6/2019    B   815    
1/7/2019    B   929    
1/8/2019    B   444    
1/9/2019    B   554    
1/10/2019   B   395    
1/10/2019   B   768
```

Output :

```
X_data(independent variables)   y_data(target)
customer  0   1     2   3         0    1
   A      855  989 454 574       395 162
   A      989  454 574 395       162 123
   A      454  574 395 162       123 342
   A      574  395 162 123       342 232
   A      395  162 123 342       232 657
   B      875  999 434 564       345 798
   B      999  434 564 345       798 875
   B      434  564 345 798       564 345   
   B      564  345 798 815       929 444
   B      345  798 815 929       444 554
   B      798  815 929 444       554 395
   B      815  929 444 554       395 768
```

In the long run , the X_data could scale upto 70 columns and the y_dat could go to 40 columns. i tried below for loop irrespective of customer but need some modification to have it at customer level.

```
data = np.array(data)
X_data, y_data = [], []
for i in range(4, len(data )-2):
    X_data.append(data[i-4:i])
    y_data.append(data[i:i+2])
```

please suggest on this.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Here's my suggestion.

First sort the data into sequences of prices (ignores dates and assumes the original list is sorted chronologically):

```
df = df.reset_index()
prices_by_customers = df.groupby('Customer')['Price']
customers = [name for name, prices in prices_by_customers]
price_sequences = pd.concat([prices.reset_index(drop=True)
                             for name, prices in prices_by_customers], 
                            axis=1, keys=customers)
```

`price_sequences`:

```
        A    B
0   855.0  875
1   989.0  999
2   454.0  434
3   574.0  564
4   395.0  345
5   162.0  798
6   123.0  815
7   342.0  929
8   232.0  444
9   657.0  554
10    NaN  395
11    NaN  768
```

Now, create the data frame you want:

```
# Add shifted columns
x_data = []
y_data = []
for customer, prices in prices_by_customers:
    x = {i: prices.shift(-i) for i in range(4)}
    y = {i: prices.shift(-i-4) for i in range(2)}
    x['Customer'] = customer
    y['Customer'] = customer
    x_data.append(pd.DataFrame(x))
    y_data.append(pd.DataFrame(y))

# Join up datasets
x_data = pd.concat(x_data)
y_data = pd.concat(y_data)
print(pd.concat([x_data, y_data], axis=1))
```

Output:

```
      0      1      2      3 Customer      0      1 Customer
0   855  989.0  454.0  574.0        A  395.0  162.0        A
1   989  454.0  574.0  395.0        A  162.0  123.0        A
2   454  574.0  395.0  162.0        A  123.0  342.0        A
3   574  395.0  162.0  123.0        A  342.0  232.0        A
4   395  162.0  123.0  342.0        A  232.0  657.0        A
5   162  123.0  342.0  232.0        A  657.0    NaN        A
6   123  342.0  232.0  657.0        A    NaN    NaN        A
7   342  232.0  657.0    NaN        A    NaN    NaN        A
8   232  657.0    NaN    NaN        A    NaN    NaN        A
9   657    NaN    NaN    NaN        A    NaN    NaN        A
10  875  999.0  434.0  564.0        B  345.0  798.0        B
11  999  434.0  564.0  345.0        B  798.0  815.0        B
12  434  564.0  345.0  798.0        B  815.0  929.0        B
13  564  345.0  798.0  815.0        B  929.0  444.0        B
14  345  798.0  815.0  929.0        B  444.0  554.0        B
15  798  815.0  929.0  444.0        B  554.0  395.0        B
16  815  929.0  444.0  554.0        B  395.0  768.0        B
17  929  444.0  554.0  395.0        B  768.0    NaN        B
18  444  554.0  395.0  768.0        B    NaN    NaN        B
19  554  395.0  768.0    NaN        B    NaN    NaN        B
20  395  768.0    NaN    NaN        B    NaN    NaN        B
21  768    NaN    NaN    NaN        B    NaN    NaN        B
```

Finally, drop NaNs etc.:

```
training_data = pd.concat([x_data, y_data], axis=1, keys=['X_data', 'y_data']).dropna()
training_data = training_data.reset_index(drop=True).drop(('y_data', 'Customer'), axis=1)
```

`training_data`:

```
   X_data                               y_data       
        0      1      2      3 Customer      0      1
0   855.0  989.0  454.0  574.0        A  395.0  162.0
1   989.0  454.0  574.0  395.0        A  162.0  123.0
2   454.0  574.0  395.0  162.0        A  123.0  342.0
3   574.0  395.0  162.0  123.0        A  342.0  232.0
4   395.0  162.0  123.0  342.0        A  232.0  657.0
5   875.0  999.0  434.0  564.0        B  345.0  798.0
6   999.0  434.0  564.0  345.0        B  798.0  815.0
7   434.0  564.0  345.0  798.0        B  815.0  929.0
8   564.0  345.0  798.0  815.0        B  929.0  444.0
9   345.0  798.0  815.0  929.0        B  444.0  554.0
10  798.0  815.0  929.0  444.0        B  554.0  395.0
11  815.0  929.0  444.0  554.0        B  395.0  768.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply bill,i want to understand why i: is required in the for loop however prices.shift(-i) is giving the same price output in iteration,can u pls let me know on this

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  `{i: prices.shift(-i) for i in range(4)}` creates a dictionary containing four price series each shifted by 0, -1, -2, -3 respectively.

Comment: If I answered your question, feel free to mark it as the answer!